# Ability to enter the same info into multiple PO lines

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to discover if there is away to choose multiple Material#'s (or PO and PO Line#'s) in Access 2007/2010 so that if I want to enter the same info for all of them then I can just do it once rather than having to look up each individual Material# and enter the info multiple times.

We import Material#'s of our product and the PO#'s and the PO Line Item#'s from SAP into Access. My job is to look through each material# and see if the Buyer correctly benchmarked the price from the quote to verify we got the proper savings amount from our vendor. There are alot of times when a single PO will have up to 50 lines on it all for different material#'s but their specs and prices will all be the same. So rather than having to enter the same comment for 50 different material#'s, I am trying to find out if there is an easier way to choose the 50 material#'s and enter the comment once for all of them. Please let me know if there is a way as it would save me alot of time and my Purchase Analyst who helped build our Access data base doesn't think there is a way but I think there must be some way to do it, whether a Macro or something else they haven't thought of.

Thanks for any help you can provide!